# Is there one line of code for changing all folders and sub folders file extensions using powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-extension, subdirectory, batch-rename

I used the following code to batch change one extension in one folder at a time.

`Dir *.mkv | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace ".mkv",".vlc" }`

What I want is to be able to have one line of code that will

- change all file extension types to one file extension
- include files inside sub folders

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, THANKS

Comment: See Get-ChildItem options. Use this to replace ‘dir’.

Comment: @user2864740 dir is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` - it makes sense to use proper names instead of aliases but there won't be any effective difference.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-Recurse` to include subfolders. Use `BaseName` which is the filename without extension.
[Read the documentation for more info on either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {"$($_.BaseName).vlc"}
```

**Edit**

Apologies, I missed this part:

> change all file extension types to one file extension

To change all file extensions you just need to exclude the `*mkv` but as covered by [LotPings's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006278/5039142) this isn't recommended; it's very easy to change the extension of files you didn't mean to. He covers using the `-Include` parameter, which is the recommended way as it filters early on.

In the interest of showing another way, you could use the `Extension` property. This allows you to leverage all of the PowerShell [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) - examples below.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".mkv"}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -in @(".mkv",".avi")}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne ".vlc"}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you also tagged it `batch-file`:

```
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do @ECHO ren "%%a" "%%~na.vlc"
```

(this is batch-file syntax. If you want to use it directly on command line)

```
for /r %a in (*.mkv) do @ECHO ren "%a" "%~na.vlc"
```

Remove `@ECHO`, if the output fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change **ALL** extensions, just use `-Include` and present a list

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\start\here -Recurse -Include ('*.mkv','*.xyz')| Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'.vlc'} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`